# PHP: How to add values in array?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to add the $user_answer value in array $array_user_answer , every button clicked.

I tried $array_user_answer[] but it's just replacing the first index value.

FYI: Don't worry about button $_POST['next_question'] it's working properly and header.

```
     $array_user_answer=array();

      if(isset($_POST['next_question']))
        {
            $answer = $_POST['answer'];
            $user_answer = $_POST['option_value'];

            $array_user_answer[] = $user_answer;

            if($answer == $user_answer)
            {
                header("Location: quiz_started?question=$next");
            }
            else
            {
                header("Location: quiz_started?question=$next");        
            }
        }
```

Comment: here you are redirecting to the next question every time. So you can not keep the answers in the array. You can store that in db or session

Comment: Where's your javascript code?

Comment: @aldrin27 i don't used js

Comment: You should look into using php [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Comment: Yes @iam-decoder is right. Use sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need [Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php):

Sessions will let you save data inbetween page calls from the same browser.
All you need to do is to call `session_start()` and use the [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) array, php will do the rest.

```
//initialize session
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['next_question']))
{
    $answer = $_POST['answer'];
    $user_answer = $_POST['option_value'];

    //add info to session array
    $_SESSION['user_answers'][] = $user_answer;

    if($answer == $user_answer)
    {
        header("Location: quiz_started?question=$next");
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location: quiz_started?question=$next");        
    }
}
```

get all answers like this:

```
print_r($_SESSION['user_answers'];
```

Unset the answers:

```
unset($_SESSION['user_answers']);
```

destroy the session entirely

```
//will delete all session info!
session_destroy();
```

Take a look at the [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).

Answer (score 0):

There is a very helpfull function called `array_push()` in `PHP`. You can add values to an existing or empty array.

You have to make a new array, for example `$myArray = array()`
Now you can do something like:

`array_push($myArray, "value 1", "value 2", "value 3")`

To know if the values are stored in the array, you can simply use the `var_dump()` function: `var_dump($myArray)`

The output will give you something like:

`array(3) { [0]=> string(7) "Value 1" [1]=> string(7) "Value 2" [2]=> string(7) "Value 3" }`

Note: The values in the array will not be stored permanently if the information is not stored somewhere (e.g. Database.. or something else), if you want to store it automatic, you could use a database or `sessions` to store the information you want to add in the array.

The `session` would look something like `$_SESSION["myArray"][]`
To add values to this session, you can do someting like `$_SESSION["myArray"] = "Value 1"`

Example:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["value"][] = uniqid();
var_dump($_SESSION["value"]);
?>
```

output: `array(10) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> string(13) "56e919195f69e" [2]=> int(0) [3]=> string(13) "56e9191a48697" [4]=> int(0) [5]=> string(13) "56e9191b171cc" [6]=> int(0) [7]=> string(13) "56e9193143838" [8]=> string(13) "56e9193c5ac39" [9]=> string(13) "56e9193dedc09" }`

Every time I refresh the page, it will add a value to my session array. To empty the session, you can use `unset($_SESSION["myArray"])` or `session_destroy()` (Will destroy all sessions where made with your script.)

If you want you can read more about this function on http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: and how do you plan on having that array persist through multiple connections?

Comment: You can use sessions instead